# Ubuntu 18.04 won't lock when lid is closed

Tags: power-management

I edited the /etc/systemd/logind.conf and modified the line HandleLidSwitch=lock but when I close the lid nothing happens and the laptop is not locked.
I don't know what to do.

Edit:
I tried to do this with the acpid service.
I created a file `/etc/acpi/lm_lid` and put this content into it:
`event=button/lid.*
action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh`
I created a file `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` and put this into it:
`#!/bin/sh

dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock`
I verified that the script is being executed when I close the lid. Any other command I put in the script is executed - except the lock itself.
When I run the script manually from the command line all the commands are executed - including the lock.

Any way to make the laptop lock when I close the lid ?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Kinda. Moved from Ubuntu 18.04 to Mint. Everything is so better ! The best thing I did since I started using Linux OS.

Comment: Which flavour of Mint, GNOME?

Comment: Cinnamon. Very convenient and efficient desktop. Much like Unity which I really loved.